# Accepting and parsing an uploaded file in a servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, file-upload

How do I get the file in a servlet running on Tomcat after using `<input type="file">` in the JSP file?

Comment: disregard the jsp comment (this an html on the client...)

Comment: You should use `edit` link to edit questions, not `add comment` link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the html side you define your form as `multipart/formdata`

```
<form class="sendform" method="POST" action="url.to.your.servlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="file" name="sendfile" value="" />

</form>
```

on the serverside you can use fileupload from [apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Tomcat 6.0 or older, then use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). It's the defacto standard to parse file uploads in servlets. If you're using Tomcat 7.0 or newer with the fresh new Servlet 3.0 API, then use API-provided [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) method.

Longer answer with detailed background information and code examples can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/upload-big-file-to-servlet/2424824#2424824).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=160) simple tutorial on jGuru. You have to use a MultipartHttpRequest and get the inputstream..